# SubscriberKit.StreamListener not working -openTok

Tags: java, android, opentok

when the subscriber's stream is interrupted due to network issue, the clients subscriber video will be paused.

But not getting the controller inside Stream-listener.

openTok versions used,

```
com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.15.3
com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.16.3
```

Code

```
SubscriberKit.StreamListener streamListener=new SubscriberKit.StreamListener() {
    @Override
    public void onReconnected(SubscriberKit subscriberKit) {
        showReconnectionDialogue("Subscriber has been reconnected",false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(SubscriberKit subscriberKit) {


        showReconnectionDialogue(getResources().getString(R.string.sesion_subscriber_alert),true);
    }
};

mSubscriber.setVideoListener(this);
mSubscriber.setStreamListener(streamListener);
mSubscriber.setSubscriberListener(mSubscriberListener);
mSession.subscribe(mSubscriber);
```

I followed [this](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/SubscriberKit.StreamListener.html) article about SubscriberKit.StreamListener